# Get a list of filename of certain extensions and write the modified output to file

Tags: linux, bash, find

I can search for all the files with certain extension inside my directory (excluding top-level) using:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.txt'
```

which returns:

```
folder1/text1.txt
folder1/text2.txt
...
```

I want to write these file names to an output file, say `file-list.txt` and change the content to:

```
Text file folder1/text1.txt
Text file folder1/text2.txt
...
```

i.e. concatenate the filenames into some longer strings. How do I do that with `bash`? I have search and learnt that `sed` should be able to achieve this result but I couldn't work myself out.

Comment: *"...but I couldn't work myself out...."* is not a good problem statement. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU find, you can use the [`-printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#index-g_t_002dprintf-70) action to format your output:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name '*.txt' -printf 'Text file %P\n'
```

where `%P` is

> File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it was found removed.

(as opposed to `%p`, which would keep the leading `./`). To get the output into a file, append a redirection `> file-list.txt` after the command.

Answer (score 2):

Append with GNU sed:

```
| sed 's/.*/Text file &/' >file-list.txt
```